# What formula can I use to calculate how much protein per 100 calories a given food has?

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

I have an Excel spreadsheet of 529 items all with calories, carbs, fats, and protein listed. I'd like to add a **grams of protein per 100 calories** column but my math ability is embarrassingly non-existent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the "protein" value is in grams, simply divide it by the "calorie" value, then multiply the result by 100.

Comment: Thank you! Also thanks to pjs36 for fixing the tags. I looked through the most popular tags but they just made me confused. I'm going to make a point to work on my math skills again sometime.